# Why is Python 3.1 throwing a SyntaxError when printing after loop?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to run this snippet in Python 3.1 console and I'm getting SyntaxError:

```
>>> while True:
...     a=5
...     if a<6:
...             break
... print("hello")
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    print("hello")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

(This is just shortened code to make a point.)

Am I missing something? Is there some other Magic I don't know about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working, if you put the whole thing in a function:

```
def test():
    while True:
        a=5
        if a<6:
            break
    print("hello")
```

If you try to do it outside a function (just in the interpreter), it does not know how to evaulate the whole thing, since it can only handle one statement at a time in the interpreter. Your `while` loop is such a statement, and your `print` stuff is such a statement, such you have two statements, but the interpreter takes only one.

Comment: Ah, didn't know it can handle only one statement - it make sence! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

You have to input an empty line into the REPL to complete the current block before you can enter a new, unindented line of code.